# Can't get clientHeight in Vue js using $el

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom, vuejs2, html-framework-7

I want to get client height of my app using this code :

```
mounted() {
    document.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (document.readyState == "complete") {
        console.log("Page completed with image and files!");
        console.log(this);
        console.log(this.$el.clientHeight);
      }
    };
}
```

In `console.log(this)` I can see my main element and `clientHeight` of that is **702**, but `console.log(this.$el.clientHeight)` result is **0**.

Also I'm using Framework7 to creating my application UI.

What can I do about this problem?
Any help will greatly appreciate.

Comment: Not even when you use `this.$nextTick(() => console.log(this.$el.clientHeight));` ? Or using a ref `this.$refs.componentId.clientHeight`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a component's height, @Victor Popescu answer is good.

But if client height size is needed, I think this way is better.

```js
new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    clientHeight: 0
},
created() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
    this.handleResize();
},
destroyed() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.handleResize);
},
methods: {
    handleResize() {
        this.clientHeight = window.innerHeight;
    }
}
});
```

```css
html, body, #app, section {
  height: 100%;
}

h2 {
padding: 2rem 0;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section>
<h2 class="title is-2">
  Height: {{ clientHeight }}
</h2>
  </section>
</div>
```

You can watch clientHeight also to set any other component's height.

```
watch: {
      clientHeight: function(val) {
          if (document.getElementById("elementId")) {
            document.getElementById("elementId").style.height = val + 'px'
          }
      }
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a `ref="potato"` on your component template, if that is an valid option for you, and then `console.log(this.$refs.potato.clientHeight);` will give you the component height.